# Delayed propagation when inserting data with the REST api?

Tags: rest-api

I've noticed that if I create a contact using the rest api, it can take a few minutes before a query will return that new contact. Is there any way to speed up the propagation so it takes a few seconds at most?

Comment: Are you querying by Id?

Comment: how exactly are you querying it.

Comment: Can you confirm that the query is a SOSL query?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the same thing. I assume it has to do with salesforce indexing of search results.

If you query by ID you will get the record immediately. If you are searching (by ID or anything else) using salesforce search box then it may be delayed.